# Allow non-admin users to view an EntityForm submission

Tags: views, entities

I've created an EntityForm wich authenticated users can submit.

Then I've created a view wich list every entityForm submissions and everyone can see this view.

Now I want to add a field to this view. This field will contain a link to this specific EntityForm submission.

2 solutions:
-Display the direct link "Entityform Submission: Link"
-Display an URL "Entityform Submission: URL"

As an admin:

[image: As an admin]

Those solutions both work, but only as an administrator!

The link is invisible for non-admin persons.
The URL leads to a "Access denied - You are not authorized to access this page."

As a non-admin:

[image: as a non-admin]

Question : How can I allow non-admin users to access entityForm submission pages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By creating a new permission maybe ? Then create the access page via an menu item with the new permssion you created
Give this permission to non authenticated users then.

Comment: You're right! I totally forgot the permission panel.